# What is DOMAIN_SEPARATOR in EIP712?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, eip712

Can someone please explain to me (with a practical example) the use of DOMAIN_SEPARATOR in EIP712 and how it ensures different signatures for the same messages by the same user in two different Dapps?

Answer (score 6):

This is a value unique to each domain that is ‘mixed in’ the signature. It makes signatures from different domains incompatible because **is designed to include bits of DApp unique information such as the name of the DApp, the intended validator contract address, the expected DApp domain name, etc.**

Source:https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712

Answer (score 3):

> It is possible that two DApps come up with an identical structure like
> Transfer(address from,address to,uint256 amount) that should not be
> compatible. By introducing a domain separator the dApp developers are
> guaranteed that there can be no signature collision.

You can see a practical example of how Uniswap uses it in [ERC721Permit.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/base/ERC721Permit.sol)

```
   function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() public view override returns (bytes32) {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encode(
                    // keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)')
                    0x8b73c3c69bb8fe3d512ecc4cf759cc79239f7b179b0ffacaa9a75d522b39400f,
                    nameHash,
                    versionHash,
                    ChainId.get(),
                    address(this)
                )
            );
    }
```

`DOMAIN_SEPARATOR` returns a hash value (bytes32) and this is hash value is used in `permit` function

```
   function permit(
        address spender,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 deadline,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) external payable override {
        require(_blockTimestamp() <= deadline, 'Permit expired');
        // it is used to create another hash value to make it unique
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                '\x19\x01',
                DOMAIN_SEPARATOR(),
                keccak256(abi.encode(PERMIT_TYPEHASH, spender, tokenId, _getAndIncrementNonce(tokenId), deadline))
            )
        );
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(spender != owner, 'ERC721Permit: approval to current owner');

        if (Address.isContract(owner)) {
            require(IERC1271(owner).isValidSignature(digest, abi.encodePacked(r, s, v)) == 0x1626ba7e, 'Unauthorized');
        } else {
            address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
            require(recoveredAddress != address(0), 'Invalid signature');
            require(recoveredAddress == owner, 'Unauthorized');
        }

        _approve(spender, tokenId);
    }
```